# Pythagoras' Theorem for Random Variables?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, orthogonality

Let $X$ be a square-integrable random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-sigma-Algebra and let $Z$ denote $Z:=E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$.

We know, since the conditional expectation is an orthogonal projection, that $X-Z$ is orthogonal to $Z$.

Moreover we know that $X-Z$ is orthogonal to 1, since they have the same expectation.

Now we have written:

$$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[((X-Z) + (Z-E[X]))^2] = E[(X-Z)^2] + E[(Z-E[X])^2]$$

by Pythagoras' Theorem. Can you state Pythagoras' Theorem for random variables (I could not find it) and explain why/how it applies here? And which assumptions are needed for that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pythagoras' theorem holds in any inner product space.

Comment: So what I know is that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ if we have a triangle. 
So here we would $a=X-Z$, $b=Z-E[X]$ and as inner product we take $a^2=E[(X-Z)^2]$ and $b^2=E[(Z-E[X])^2]$. 
What we Need is that the sides corresponding to length $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, so we Need $X-Z$ and $Z-E[X]$ to be orthogonal. But why does this hold? Or am I wrong in my conclusions?

Comment: It's just the axioms of an inner product and the norm induced by one: if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then $\| x + y \|^2 = \langle x+y,x+y \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle + 2 \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle$, but $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$...

Comment: Thanks, that is a better Explanation of what I tried to derive above. But now, in my example, why do I know that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal? Why are $X-Z$ and $Z-E[X]$ orthogonal?

Comment: When $E[X]=0$, $X-Z$ and $Z$ are orthogonal in the inner product $\langle X,Y \rangle = E[XY]$; this is the orthogonality condition you mentioned. If I remember correctly the situation is a bit more complicated when $E[X] \neq 0$.

Comment: In our example, $E[X] \neq 0$. We want to show that $Var(X)=E[Var(X\mid \mathcal{F})] + Var(E[X \mid \mathcal{F}])$ for some arbitrary square-integrable random variable $X$.

Comment: So for mean zero variables you have orthogonality in that actual inner product; for general variables you also have "orthogonality" after subtracting off the means, but I think the resulting function is not actually an inner product (to my recollection).